# Jquery How to change text of certain class inside $(this) selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

My problem is quite obvious but I don't know why its solution is taking so much time.

Look at my html:

```
  {% for d in data %}       
            <div class="chat_list" data-id={{d.id}}>
              <div class="chat_people" >               
                <div class="chat_ib"  >
                  <h5><span class="chat_date">
                 </span></h5>                  
                </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

I want to append text on click of certain div.Things I tried out in jquery:

```
$('.chat_list').on('click', function(event){  
    event.preventDefault();
    $( '.chat_date', this).text('hhh')
    $(this).find('.chat_date' ).text('hhh')
    $(this).find( 'chat_people').find('chat_ib').find('.chat_date' ).text('hhh')
 });
```

Nothing worked out. When only do `$( '.chat_date').text('hhh')`  text get appears on every div. Any good solution to this?

Comment: Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/grex2ndy/. Check the console for errors, and ensure you're running the JS code *after* the DOM has loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this script and don't forget to set the position of each div. This script runs all but the letters will overlap each other.
for position you can use $('').css({top:12px})

```
<script>    

    $(document).ready(function(){   
     $('.chat_list').on('click', function(event){  
        event.preventDefault();
        //$( '.chat_date', this).text('hhh') or $(this).find('.chat_date' ).text('hhh')
        $(this).find('.chat_date' ).text('hhh')
        $(this).find('.chat_people' ).text('hhh')
        $(this).find('.chat_ib').text('hhh')

        //$(this).find( 'chat_people').find('chat_ib').find('.chat_date' ).text('hhh') is not function
     }); 
     });
     </script>
```